# Pressing the button transfers the data to the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have buttons, which are numbered from 1 to 9. they are created and numbered in a loop.

```
 <% for j in (1..9) %>
        <%= button_to j, xml_show1_url(:id => j), {class: "btn btn-secondary"} %>
   <% end %>
```

When you click on one of the buttons. For example, with value 1. you need to send this value to the function. This number is required for insertion into a string, and this line is a path to the file. Here is a function that parses the desired html file

```
def show
   @some_params = params[:id]
   @file = File.open("#{Rails.root}/app/data/home_work_#{@some_params}.xml", "r")
   @doc = Nokogiri::XML(@file)
   @attributes = @doc.at('subject')['id']
   @subjects = @doc.xpath("//subject")
   end
```

How do I implement it! Help! TY

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code. Try this:

```
<% for j in (1..9) %>
    <%= link_to "Button name", path_to_your_action(id: j), :class => 'btn btn-secondary' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: When I click on the button it goes on the correct path, but an error appears. However, when you go over the same cops, everything works, I do not understand why